# What approach to use when generating qr code in CQRS architecture?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs, webapi, mediatr

I need to generate a qr code in my web api and save the data encrypted in the qr code to the database.
I have an action method in my controller GenerateQrCode which should generate a qr code through an external service, save the qr code data to the database, and return json with the generated qr in base64 to the front, the question is, how can I generate a qr code in one request, save it in db and get response as json using cqrs architecture, split generation into command and request? and in the action method to call the command first and then the request to receive? Or should there be two different action methods to be used in the same operation on the front in succession? As far as I know, cqrs assumes that the command does not return a result.

My action method:

```
app.MapGet("/generateQrCode", async ([FromServices] IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint, [FromServices] IMediator mediator) =>
{
    var result = await mediator.Send(new GetGeneratedQrCodesQuery());
    return result;
});
```

My QueryHandler:

```
internal class GetGeneratedQrCodesQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetGeneratedQrCodesQuery, string>
{
    private readonly IQrCodeClient<string> _qrCodeGenerator;
    public GetGeneratedQrCodesQueryHandler(IQrCodeClient<string> qrCodeGenerator) => _qrCodeGenerator = qrCodeGenerator;
    public async Task<string> Handle(GetGeneratedQrCodesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Here i want to save qr code data to db...
        return await _qrCodeGenerator.GetQrCode(request.ReceiverData.ToString(), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

On the front side of the system, a button is supposed to be pressed by pressing which a request is sent to the generateQrCode method, a qr is generated, the data is stored in the database, and the qr is returned as a json field in base64.

I will be most grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First off, CQRS isn't an architecture, it's a principle and nothing of your use case is a case for DDD.

Second, your naming is a mess.

You call your message `GetGeneratedQrCodesQuery`, but in reality it's not retrieving it (query), but generating it ( `_qrCodeGenerator.GetQrCode(...)`).
As such, the proper naming would be `GenerateQrCode` (generate and persists teh QR Code) and after it's generated (and persisted), you would retrieve it with a query `GetQrCode/RetrieveQrCode`.

This can be in the same action or separate. Since MediatR isn't an async messaging library but a in-process synchronous library, you know that after awaiting the first command, the QR Code will be persisted, otherwise it would throw an exception, which allows you to call the query right after.

Comment: I still don't quite understand where the generated data should be stored in the database and where the return to the front should be.

Comment: You have provided to little information on this. Generally store it where ever you want. You will have a repository for saving and retrieving it, what store you implement under the hood is up to your and your requirements. Anything from relational databases, to file/object storages (S3, Azure Blobs, MinIO)  or distributed memory caches (redis). All you need is a unique key to identify and retrieve it. It can be a compound key that's generated by our object ids and meta data, i.e. `Order-66` (a QR Code for an order with the id 66 (pun intended)) or `Invoice-42` for an invoice with id 42

Comment: Whether to use relation, object storage or memory caches, is up to you. Do you need to store it to reduce response time when user shows it? (i.e. codes appear when user browses the catalog?) but don't have to store it historically, then memory cache is a good solution (QR codes can be regenerated easily so there's rarely a point to save them presistently for a later point of time)